# The algorithm behind InputForm for machine numbers

Tags: numerics, implementation-details, conversion, machine-precision, reference-request

There are several questions on this site about implementing fast CSV/TSV export for machine numbers without loss of precision. Recently I [discovered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173174/is-it-possible-to-get-from-decimalform-just-the-original-number#comment454689_173174) that `Export` merely applies `ToString[#, InputForm] &` to every number in the table for conversion it into a string:

```
Trace[ExportString[{-7756.0224337393065}, "TSV"], ToString] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {ToString[-7756.0224337393065, InputForm], "-7756.0224337393065"}
> ```

Unfortunately there seems to be no built-in alternative to `InputForm` in *Mathematica* for obtaining the correct digits of machine numbers, even `RealDigits` isn't precise:

```
x = 44802.395880518656;
ToExpression@ToString[x, InputForm] - x
FromDigits@RealDigits[x] - x
```

> ```
> 0.
>
> -7.27596*10^-12
> ```

`InputForm` works correctly but very slow. From the other hand, it shouldn't be too difficult to re-implement the algorithm behind this conversion as a compilable function in order to get huge speed-up.

Does anybody know what the algorithm is? Probably it isn't proprietary and can be found in the literature.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7153979/590388

Comment: `RealDigits` appears to drop the digit which is not precise. `x = 44802.395880518658; InputForm@x` returns `44802.395880518656`

Comment: Consider using `Internal`DoubleToString`. It offers a ~3-4x speedup: `arr = RandomReal[{0, 50000}, 10^6];
AbsoluteTiming[ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ arr] // First
AbsoluteTiming[Internal`DoubleToString /@ arr] // First` but it also loses the last digit.

Comment: You may find interesting the algorithms referenced in [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/81039) answer.

Comment: Tangentially related: "[Is `NumberForm` double rounding numbers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204359/280)"

Answer (score 3):

This section of my answer previously showed that `Export[fname, data, "TSV"]`  is incredibly slow (~500 seconds for exporting 10^5 * 10 reals), but this is easily worked around by `WriteString[fname, ExportString[data, "TSV"]]`.

All of this is less relevant for CSV export, as I demonstrated below and the foolishly missed while going on to ramble about TSV export. But even for CSV a small speedup is possible with this workaround.

---

I would *assume* that what you mean by "the algorithm behind `InputForm`" is defined by low-level code, something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
```

and

```
printf("%.*f", DBL_DIG, x);
```

*Where* the implementation of *that* is defined, I do not know, but I would expect that to follow the IEEE-754 standard ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), [Official paywall](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4610935)).

Any (finite) binary float can be represented by a terminating sequence of decimal digits, of approximately 52 decimal digits of precision, but (provably) 17 digits are always enough. However...

```
N @ MachinePrecision
(* 15.9546 *)

1 + $MachineEpsilon
(* 1. *)

InputForm @ %
(* 1.0000000000000002 *)

SetPrecision[%, 16]
(* 1.000000000000000 *)
```

The second paragraph of section 5.12 of 2008 IEEE-754 clearly states

> Implementations shall provide conversions between each supported binary format and external decimal character sequences such that, under roundTiesToEven, conversion from the supported format to external decimal character sequence and back recovers the original floating-point representation, except that a
>   signaling NaN might be converted to a quiet NaN. See 5.12.1 and 5.12.2 for details.

- `InputForm` is compliant with this, though I would expect `44802.39588051865` to be represented as `44802.395880518648` and not to remain as `...865`.
- `RealDigits` is not a true conversion to an "external decimal representation", though one could expect it to behave as such. It discards the digit of least precision. Annoyingly, `FromDigits` converts back to a **rational** number.
- <s>`` Internal`DoubleToString `` is quite fast (but not orders of magnitude faster) and it suffers from the same problem as `RealDigits` -- it discards the ULP. I'd say, this is blatant non-compliance with the standard.</s> I can no longer reproduce this on my machine. Perhaps `DoubleToString` is compliant after all.
- `ToString@SetPrecision[x, 17]` should give always correct results and is not too bad in terms of speed. In fact, you don't even need `ToString` here.

But

```
Export["test.csv",
  SetPrecision[RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^5, 10}], 17], "CSV"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {20.1076, "test.csv"} *)
Export["test.csv", RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^5, 10}], "CSV"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {15.307, "test.csv"} *)
With[{arr = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^5, 10}]}, 
  Export["test.csv", arr, "CSV"] // AbsoluteTiming]
(* {15.2228, "test.csv"} *)
With[{arr = SetPrecision[RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^5, 10}], 17]}, 
  Export["test.csv", arr, "CSV"] // AbsoluteTiming]
(* {19.3445, "test.csv"} *)
RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^5, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
With[{arr = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^5, 10}]}, 
  SetPrecision[arr, 17] // AbsoluteTiming // First]
(* 0.026734 *)
(* 0.840021 *)
```

Basically, generating `10^6` numbers is fast (its timing is negligible), converting them to 17 digits of precision is also very fast, and frankly, I don't think that the unpacked array causes the slowdown in the CSV export. What's more likely, is that there is simply more bytes to write.

Bottom line: `Export` is simply that slow.

Here's a not-very-thoroughly-though-out alternative which is already quite a bit faster:

```
With[{rand = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^5, 10}]},
 Block[{arr = SetPrecision[rand, 17], str},
   str = Map[ToString, arr, {-1}];
   Export["test.dat", StringRiffle[str], "String"]] // AbsoluteTiming]
(* {7.75655, "test.dat"} *)
```

This can all be much faster if you're prepared to downgrade from 17 to 16 digits of precision - the `SetPrecision` and `ToString` can be replaced by a single `` Internal`DoubleToString ``.

You may likely be interested in studying `Put`, `PutAppend` (which, by the way, generate output in `InputForm`) as well as `Write` and related functions. They'll likely be somewhat complicated to get to work properly, but can offer large speedups.

---

## `LibraryLink` solution

*This is a work-in-progress which I'll fine-tune a bit over the next few days. In principle, [Henrik Schumacher has already made a solution here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171587/26956), but OP apparently had some troubles getting it to work, so I'll show a bare-bones example to get started.*

I'm assuming, that a C-compiler is set up and `` <<CCompilerDriver` `` has been executed. Start by creating a directory and creating a file, `ExportTable.c` in it with the following code:

```
 #include "WolframLibrary.h"
 #include <float.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 DLLEXPORT int fastExportCSV(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {

        double* data;
        char* fname = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[0]);
        mint i = 0;
        mint j = 0;
//        mint len;  // correct handling of array dimensions still to be implemented

        MTensor in = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[1]);
//      len = libData->MTensor_getFlattenedLength(in);
        data = libData->MTensor_getRealData(in);

        FILE * ofile;
        ofile = fopen(fname, "w");

        for(i = 0; i<100000; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j<10; j++) {
                fprintf(ofile, "%.*f,", DBL_DIG, data[10*i + j]);
            }
            fprintf(ofile, "\n");
        }
        fclose(ofile);

        MArgument_setUTF8String(Res,fname);
        return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Now go over to Mathematica to set everything up there:

```
lib = CreateLibrary[{"ExportTable.c"}, "ExportTable"]
fastExportCSV = LibraryFunctionLoad[
    lib, 
    "fastExportCSV",
    {"UTF8String", {Real, 2, "Constant"}}, 
    "UTF8String"
    ]
```

Because the dimensions of the array are hard-coded right now, you have to feed a 2-dimensional `Real` array with at least 10^6 elements and the program will write them as a 10^5*10 CSV table. Like so:

```
fastExportCSV["D:\\Larkin\\Dev\\LLTutorial\\test2.dat", 
  RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10^5, 10}]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.958084, "D:\\Larkin\\Dev\\LLTutorial\\test2.dat"} *)
```

Of course, this is duplication of the linked answer, but in simpler, purely C code.

Comment: In the [linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173174/280) question I've already found a [faster](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173174/is-it-possible-to-get-the-original-number-from-decimalform#comment454683_173174) alternative to ``Internal`DoubleToString``: it is `DecimalForm` combined with `SetPrecision`. The problem is that it doesn't allow to recover the original decimal representation of the numbers exactly (as well as ``Internal`DoubleToString``).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That faster alternative is quite a fine example of what in Russia we call *костыли*. Anyway, your words "the original decimal representation" suggest some confusion about they way, numbers are handled, at least on an intuitive level. In the case of your linked question, the numbers cannot and will not be "exactly" represented (your complaint about the changing last digit). If you want an exact decimal representation, you should input numbers with arbitrary precision, e.g. ``-56705.907687414737`17``. (cont'd)

Comment: Note, then, that ``x = -56705.907687414737; y = -56705.907687414737`17; ExportString[{x,y},"TSV"]`` will return ``-56705.907687414736 -56705.907687414737``. Besides that, you say that `DecimalForm[-38741.90768741473, Infinity]` changes the last digit to `2`. I, unfortunately, don't have v11.3 to test with, but both `InputForm` and `DoubleToString` show me the exact input, regardless if the last digit is 2 or 3. This seems to be a bug of `DecimalForm`

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov anyway, it would be helpful if you specify your problem more completely (including the background). Why exactly do you care specifically about the *decimal* representation of your numbers when they, likely have been obtained through calculations with *binary double-precision floats*? If that is not the case, then calculations ought to have been done in arbitrary precision, in which case the numbers should be stored as such. In this case, their `InputForm` and/or `ToString`, etc conserves their decimal representation to the arbitrary precision that was given.

Comment: The numbers are generated by another application and then `Import`ed by *Mathematica*. `Export` allows to generate exactly the same file, but very slow. My goal is to add two columns into that TSV file.

Comment: I see. I'll get to work and have a look. Do you need to do manipulations with these numbers, or just append to a table?

Comment: These two columns are generated from numbers in other columns, but original contents of the file shouldn't be changed.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov if `Export` suits your needs, I just found that `str = ExportString[data, "TSV"];` then `WriteString[filename, str]` is many-many times faster than direct export.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov please see the new code at the top of my answer.

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use? On my machive with version 11.3 `ExportString` is 38% faster than `Export` for `"Table"` format and has no advantages for `"CSV"` format.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov v10.2

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I have tried with v11.1.1 and it is showing the same inferior performance for `Export` and `"TSV"` as compared to `ExportString`.

Comment: AFAIK the `"CSV"` export was improved in version 11.2. Probably it affects `"TSV"` too.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov so what are your timings like then? If ~10 seconds for a million `Real` numbers are too much for you, the next step would be to offload the work to some `LibraryLink` functionality; C code can read and write files very quickly. But it gets much harder when the records of the TSV file are not just rows of numbers (i.e. the output to the file isn't simply a packed array).

Comment: A `LibraryLink` solution would be nice, but I think that even `Compile` is sufficient for obtaining good performance. My file contains strings only on the first row (see `dat` at the top of the [linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173174/280) question).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I've just realized, that I've been rambling about TSV export (replaced that section with a tl;dr) while CSV export was from the start quite reasonable, ~20 seconds with `Export`, can be accelerated to ~8 with some hacks. But I don't think that compile will solve your problems. Reimplementing the IEEE standard even in a compile will almost certainly be not faster than an `InputForm` call. As it seems, MMA is quite slow at writing to files: 18MB string with `WriteString` still takes over 2 seconds. My idea is to pass the array of numbers to C code and have the export done (contd)

Comment: entirely within the C function.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov And anyway, a `Compile` based solution is impossible, since `Compile` cannot return strings or even characters, so you'll be back to square one.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov the `LibraryLink` functionality has already been done by Henrik Schumacher in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171587/26956), as it appears. Is there still some deficiency?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77694/discussion-between-lllamnyp-and-alexey-popkov).