# Is NumberForm double rounding numbers?

Tags: numerics, implementation-details, conversion, python, rounding

A number like 0.644696875 is represented internally as 0.6446968749999...:

```
N[FromDigits[RealDigits[0.644696875, 2], 2], $MachinePrecision]
(* 0.6446968749999999 *)
```

So if I ask `NumberForm` to print this number with 8 decimals, I would expect it to be 0.64469687 and not 0.64469688 because the digit after the 87 is a 4 which is less than 5. But it is not what we get with `NumberForm`:

```
NumberForm[0.644696875, {8, 8}]
(* 0.64469688 *)
```

So it looks like we have here two round operations when only one was requested:

- First Rounding: From 0.6446968749999999 to 0.644696875
- Second Rounding: From 0.644696875 to 0.64469688

I found this while comparing to Python, which doesn't double round. This leads to a result which I believe is correct:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "'{:.8f}'.format(0.644696875)"]
(* 0.64469687 *)
```

Also notice that this floating point number is stored in the same way in both systems:

```
Divide @@ ExternalEvaluate["Python", "0.644696875.as_integer_ratio()"] == FromDigits[RealDigits[0.644696875, 2], 2]
(* True *)
```

**Is *Mathematica* double rounding? Can this be avoided while still using machine numbers?**

Motivation: I'm working on making a hash on an array of floating point numbers. This calculation should be the same from *Mathematica* and from Python. For this I need to be able to produce the same string representation of numbers in both system. This has proven more challenging than expected.

**Update**: I think *Mathematica* is double rounding just like Java does. Please see:

- [Why do C and Java round floats differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778637/why-do-c-and-java-round-floats-differently)

**Update2**: I asked support about this [CASE:4304365] and they said "It does appear that NumberForm is not behaving properly".

Comment: Probably what you want is `RealDigits[Round[u, 10^-8]]`.

Comment: Related: "[Efficient Round edition with different rounding direction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193412/280)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for the info. However, I don't think that the issue is the rounding direction. For example, NumberForm[0.644696874999999947, 8] rounds to 0.64469687 and if we remove the last 7 effectively making the number smaller then the rounded version increases as NumberForm[0.64469687499999994, 8] returns 0.64469688

Comment: I didn't meant that the issue with NumberForm is the rounding direction, but if you need to reproduce the Python result exactly, then Round is probably what you need (but it may have another rounding direction).

Answer (score 3):

I think [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm), being a formatting wrapper, formats the machine number using the available digits that are given to it. For your example, the available digits are:

```
.644696875 //FullForm
```

> 0.644696875`

So, the double rounding you're observing is due to the following:

1. Mathematica uses a rounded representation of the machine number for display
2. [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) rounds the displayed number

**Misconception**

I think you have a misconception about [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision). When you do

```
N[FromDigits[RealDigits[0.644696875, 2], 2], $MachinePrecision]
```

you are actually creating an extended precision object with [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision) digits, and not a machine number. Compare:

```
exact = FromDigits[RealDigits[0.644696875, 2], 2];
N[exact, MachinePrecision] //FullForm
N[exact, $MachinePrecision] //FullForm
```

> 0.644696875`
>
> 0.6446968749999999470645661858725361526`15.954589770191003

Notice how the latter number has digits following the `. This is the signature of an extended precision number. If you want to create a [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision) object with [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N), you need to use the single argument version, or you need to specify [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision) and not [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$MachinePrecision).

**Workaround**

I think you can take your observations and create a workaround by first converting to an extended precision number and then using [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm):

```
myNumberForm[n_?MachineNumberQ, spec__] := NumberForm[
    SetPrecision[n, $MachinePrecision],
    spec
]
```

Then:

```
myNumberForm[0.644696875`, {8,8}]
```

> 0.64469687

Comment: It would be valuable to know the algorithm which *Mathematica* uses for creation of rounded representation of the machine numbers for display (via `InputForm` or `FullForm`). I already asked about it here: "[The algorithm behind `InputForm` for machine numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173201/280)."

Comment: I'm puzzled by situations like this: `NumberForm[39201.327646149446, {Infinity, 13}]` returns `39201.3276461494400`. Note that it has dropped the last digit `6` and hasn't rounded the last `4` to `5`. Why is that? Is it expected behavior? Note that `FullForm` correctly returns the original number. I asked about it some time ago: "[Is it possible to get the original number from `DecimalForm`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173174/280)"